# Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 and Content Porter SP2 Error updating keywords

Tags: tridion, content-porter-2009

I'm getting an error when trying to import a Content Porter package that contains only a single category with some keywords.

The category exists on the target server, the differences are in the metadata schema attached to the keywords.

The category represents the navigation and I want to update the metadata on the production server with that from the UAT server. However it seems like instead of updating the keywords on the target server, it is trying to create new keywords, hence the error:

```
<tcm:Token>tcm:0-0-0</tcm:Token></tcm:Line>
<tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040329" Cause="true">
<![CDATA[Name, Key must all be unique for items of type: Keyword within this Category and its BluePrint context. Source or sources of conflict: tcm:4-13012-1024.]]>   
<tcm:Token>Name , Key</tcm:Token>
<tcm:Token>RESID_15309</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>RESID_15293</tcm:Token>
<tcm:Token>tcm:4-13012-1024</tcm:Token>
```

I've definitely exported at the tcmn:0-4-1 publication (01 Schemas). I would have thought it would match on name and update as it does with a Component.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the Title (Name) of the Keyword and it's field Key must be unique. I think what happens in your case is that the Title is different, but the Key is the same. So Content Porter tries to create a new Keyword (because of the different Title), but it fails because another Keyword (tcm:4-13012-1024) with the same Key already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're having a similar described in the following Content Porter hotfix:

> CP_2009.0.67032 Minimize Text
>
> If an item has been localized and renamed, Content Porter can't find
>   its parent shared item and tries to create a new one. [Error]Key must
>   be unique for items of type: Keyword within this Category and its
>   BluePrint context.

You can download the hotfixes from https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/ContentPorter_2009/index.aspx (log in required)

Comment: Hi John, the issue was as Mihai pointed out that someone had renamed an item on the UAT system and that was not being matched. I didn't install this hotfix in the end.